# Is there a way to access variables defined in rust macros from a passed expr?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

Assuming I want to make the following macro work:

```rust
macro_rules! process_numbers {
    ($name:ident, $process:expr) => {
        let $name: Vec<_> = vec![0, 1, 2].iter().map(|num| {
            println!("{}", path); // dummy preprocessing
            let foo = 3; // some other preprocessing involving side-effects
            $process
        }).collect();
    }
}

process_numbers!(name, {
    num + foo
});
```

Is there a way so that I could access `num` and `foo` from within `$process`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rust macros are [hygienic](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-min-hygiene.html). This means that identifiers defined within a macro's body won't leak out of it.

One way to solve this is to modify the macro such that it *receives* the identifiers as parameters.

```
macro_rules! process_numbers {
    ($name:ident, |$num:ident, $foo: ident| $process:expr) => {
        let $name: Vec<_> = vec![0, 1, 2].iter().map(|$num| {
            println!("{}", path); // dummy preprocessing
            let $foo = 3; // some other preprocessing involving side-effects
            $process
        }).collect();
    }
}

process_numbers!(name, |num, foo| {
    num + foo
});
```

Here, I'm using syntax that looks like a closure, which suggests that `|num, foo|` declare parameters (they actually declare variables – close enough!).

Another way would be to make the `$process` argument a literal closure (or any invokable expression) that the macro would invoke, passing `num` and `foo` as arguments.

```
macro_rules! process_numbers {
    ($name:ident, $process:expr) => {
        let $name: Vec<_> = vec![0, 1, 2].iter().map(|num| {
            println!("{}", path); // dummy preprocessing
            let foo = 3; // some other preprocessing involving side-effects
            $process(num, foo)
        }).collect();
    }
}

process_numbers!(name, |num, foo| {
    num + foo
});
```